# Nasty nested JSON to data frame in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have a couple of JSON inputs as below.

Input1:

```
{"booking":{"id":"54092","createdOn":"2016-10-06T06:29:00.0000000+0000","bookingDateTime":"2016-10-08T06:45:00.0000000+0000","checkInDateTime":null,"checkOutDateTime":null,"tableNumbers":null,"pax":3,"type":"calling","status":"booked","source":"concierge","specialInstruction":"test hoppi","outlet":{"id":"46a97c2e-c921-4339-819c-50e17f25d09a","name":"Hoppipolla"},"customer":{"name":"Hoppi","email":"hoppi@xmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"8901234567"}},"eventType":"booked","serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T06:28:25.0000558+0000"}

{"booking":{"id":"54093","createdOn":"2016-10-06T06:30:00.0000000+0000","bookingDateTime":"2016-10-08T06:46:00.0000000+0000","checkInDateTime":null,"checkOutDateTime":null,"tableNumbers":null,"pax":3,"type":"calling","status":"booked","source":"concierge","specialInstruction":"test hoppi","outlet":{"id":"46a97c2e-c922-4339-819c-50e17f25d09a","name":"Hoppipolla"},"customer":{"name":"Ravi","email":"ravi@xmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"8901234548"}},"eventType":"booked","serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T06:28:25.0000558+0000"}
```

Input2:

```
{"feedback":{"dateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:05.0000730+0000","customerName":"mytestdevcog","averageRating":4,"isNegativeByComments":false,"outlet":{"id":"f9e9c21f-2e52-462e-a1f2-012dab216d27","name":"cholan 's Darbar"},"customer":{"name":"mytestdevcog","email":"mytestdevcog123@gmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"7895478745"},"responses":[{"question":"Was your waiting time too long?","response":"No","questionType":"yes_no"},{"question":"Service","response":"3","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"desserts","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Comments","response":"good","questionType":"short_answer"},{"question":"How likely is it that you would recommend us to a friend or colleague?","response":"5","questionType":"nps"},{"question":"Portion Size","response":"5","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Indian Food","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Desert spread","response":"4","questionType":"rating"}]},"serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:27.0000644+0000"}

{"feedback":{"dateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:05.0000730+0000","customerName":"mytestdevcog","averageRating":4,"isNegativeByComments":false,"outlet":{"id":"f9e9c21f-2e52-462e-a1f2-012dab216d27","name":"cholan 's Darbar"},"customer":{"name":"mytestdevcog","email":"mytestdevcog123@gmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"7895478745"},"responses":[{"question":"Was your waiting time too long?","response":"No","questionType":"yes_no"},{"question":"Service","response":"3","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"desserts","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Comments","response":"good","questionType":"short_answer"},{"question":"How likely is it that you would recommend us to a friend or colleague?","response":"5","questionType":"nps"},{"question":"Portion Size","response":"5","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Indian Food","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Desert spread","response":"4","questionType":"rating"}]},"serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:27.0000644+0000"}
```

Would require two seperate dataframes for two inputs. How can this be achieved in R?

Comment: Please edit your json input data first. It looks wierd.

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON(input1)`. However, you need to make your inputs valid JSON. And you might be better off reading directly from the source into R

Comment: Your JSON has unmasked PII.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, your json contains an error. The third and fourth strings actually contain "cholan's darbar", which must be escaped before you can parse it as json.

For the sake of your question (about obtaining the two datasets) I corrected directly the string. Here is how it could be done:

```
library(jsonlite)

s1 <- '{"booking":{"id":"54092","createdOn":"2016-10-06T06:29:00.0000000+0000","bookingDateTime":"2016-10-08T06:45:00.0000000+0000","checkInDateTime":null,"checkOutDateTime":null,"tableNumbers":null,"pax":3,"type":"calling","status":"booked","source":"concierge","specialInstruction":"test hoppi","outlet":{"id":"46a97c2e-c921-4339-819c-50e17f25d09a","name":"Hoppipolla"},"customer":{"name":"Hoppi","email":"hoppi@xmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"8901234567"}},"eventType":"booked","serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T06:28:25.0000558+0000"}'

s2 <- '{"booking":{"id":"54093","createdOn":"2016-10-06T06:30:00.0000000+0000","bookingDateTime":"2016-10-08T06:46:00.0000000+0000","checkInDateTime":null,"checkOutDateTime":null,"tableNumbers":null,"pax":3,"type":"calling","status":"booked","source":"concierge","specialInstruction":"test hoppi","outlet":{"id":"46a97c2e-c922-4339-819c-50e17f25d09a","name":"Hoppipolla"},"customer":{"name":"Ravi","email":"ravi@xmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"8901234548"}},"eventType":"booked","serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T06:28:25.0000558+0000"}'
```

in the following two strings I manually corrected "cholan's Darbar" to "cholan **\'s** Darbar"

```
s3 <- '{"feedback":{"dateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:05.0000730+0000","customerName":"mytestdevcog","averageRating":4,"isNegativeByComments":false,"outlet":{"id":"f9e9c21f-2e52-462e-a1f2-012dab216d27","name":"cholan \'s Darbar"},"customer":{"name":"mytestdevcog","email":"mytestdevcog123@gmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"7895478745"},"responses":[{"question":"Was your waiting time too long?","response":"No","questionType":"yes_no"},{"question":"Service","response":"3","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"desserts","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Comments","response":"good","questionType":"short_answer"},{"question":"How likely is it that you would recommend us to a friend or colleague?","response":"5","questionType":"nps"},{"question":"Portion Size","response":"5","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Indian Food","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Desert spread","response":"4","questionType":"rating"}]},"serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:27.0000644+0000"}'

s4 <- '{"feedback":{"dateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:05.0000730+0000","customerName":"mytestdevcog","averageRating":4,"isNegativeByComments":false,"outlet":{"id":"f9e9c21f-2e52-462e-a1f2-012dab216d27","name":"cholan \'s Darbar"},"customer":{"name":"mytestdevcog","email":"mytestdevcog123@gmail.com","countryCallingCode":"91","phone":"7895478745"},"responses":[{"question":"Was your waiting time too long?","response":"No","questionType":"yes_no"},{"question":"Service","response":"3","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"desserts","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Comments","response":"good","questionType":"short_answer"},{"question":"How likely is it that you would recommend us to a friend or colleague?","response":"5","questionType":"nps"},{"question":"Portion Size","response":"5","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Indian Food","response":"4","questionType":"rating"},{"question":"Desert spread","response":"4","questionType":"rating"}]},"serverDateTime":"2016-10-06T09:24:27.0000644+0000"}'


j1 <- fromJSON(s1)
j2 <- fromJSON(s2)
j3 <- fromJSON(s3)
j4 <- fromJSON(s4)

rbind(j1, j2)

rbind(j3, j4)
```